# how can I use EntityRuler for persian(farsi) language?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to create a `NER` for get the entities of the sentence `(persian-farsi)` and the spacy doesn't have the `Persian` language the `sentence` look like this

```
en --> 'I bought 5 apples from Richard for $ 45'
fa --> 'من ۵ تا سیب از ریچارد خریدم به قیمت ۴۵ دلار'

output = {
    'product': 'apples',
    'quantity': '5',
    'person': 'Richard',
    'price': '45',
}
```

I do that in rule based but it's not good for real product

if there is better way to do that let me know

Answer (score 1):

You would need to train your own NER model using sample data.

Maybe take a look at the [spaCy course](https://course.spacy.io/en), which goes over training a model and what good training data looks like.